# Are weapon/gadget noises audible to the other team?

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

When I aim down sights, switch weapons, prepare a gadget, etc., I hear a noise. Can other players hear these noises as well? If so, are there any instances where I hear a noise that they don't, or vice-versa?

Comment: AFAIK certain are, and certain aren't. Doing ADS isn't audible to others, but laying a claymore for example, you can hear the click at the end of placing it on the ground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every sound you make is also hear-able for others. But for you it's obviously a bit louder since you're the source.

I recommend you to check this video:

Starts at 01:10 because everything before that is unneeded for your question (and IMO also the only BS thing in the video).

There are 2 things the video doesn't tell you though:

- Rappel does make sound which everyone can hear, and depending if you rappel from the roof or not it makes a different sound.
- Gadget placement like breach-charges and clustercharges also make a lot of noise.

So keep that in mind when you use them.

Comment: Siege actually has a really complex sound engine as sound design was/is one of there big focuses. You can check [out this video](https://youtu.be/ti6ZWRSiqpQ) for a bit closer look into how the games sounds work.